# Looking for a torch.imshow() 'like' command

Tags: image, matplotlib, pytorch, tensor, imshow

Say that i have a variable image (which is currently located on the gpu), sized `[32,1,256,256]` where 32 is the batch size, 1 is the amount of channels (gray scale).

Instead of ploting this:

```
plt.imshow(img[0,0,:,:].cpu().detach(),'gray');plt.show()
```

I wish i could do
`torch.imshow(img,8,'gray')` and it will subplot 8 images from my batch
is there any thing like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`torchvision.utils.make_grid`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/utils.html#torchvision.utils.make_grid): It will convert the `[32, 1, 256,256]` tensor into a grid of 32 images. You still need to use `plt` to actually plot the image grid to screen.

Answer (score 1):

[Cudacanvas](https://pypi.org/project/cudacanvas/) is something you could use, I don't think it has the same argument as imshow but it avoids cpu transfer, so you can just inject a pytorch tensor image into it without any problems